# Bluemix Python Flask app passing list parameter to template using list.append()

Tags: python, flask, ibm-cloud, object-storage

I'm passing a list of strings from my flask app to the html template, which works perfectly fine until I attempt to append the list. I've tested my usage of the append method using a client-side python script and it's working. I'm perplexed as to why my appending of the list causes an internal server error. Here's the section of my template which uses the parameters

```
<ul>
    {% for file in files %}
    <li>{{ file }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

And here's the route in my flask app

```
@app.route('/')
def main():
    FILES = [ 'test1', 'test2' ]

    # Iterate through each file in the cloud storage container
    for container in conn.get_account()[1]:
        for data in conn.get_container(container['name'])[1]:
            print 'object: {0}t size: {1}t date: {2}'.format(data['name'], data['bytes'], data['last_modified'])
            FILES.append('test3')
    return render_template('index.html', files = FILES)
```

The line FILES.append('test3') is causing the problem, but I'm not sure why. When I comment this line out, the list is passed to the template as you'd expect.

Here's the full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vcap/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/vcap/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/home/vcap/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/vcap/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/vcap/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/vcap/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/vcap/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/vcap/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/vcap/app/server.py", line 93, in main
    for container in conn.get_account()[1]:
  File "/home/vcap/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/swiftclient/client.py", line 1615, in get_account
    full_listing=full_listing)
  File "/home/vcap/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/swiftclient/client.py", line 1553, in _retry
    self.url, self.token = self.get_auth()
  File "/home/vcap/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/swiftclient/client.py", line 1507, in get_auth
    timeout=self.timeout)
  File "/home/vcap/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/swiftclient/client.py", line 617, in get_auth
    auth_version=auth_version)
  File "/home/vcap/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/swiftclient/client.py", line 517, in get_auth_keystone
    ksclient, exceptions = _import_keystone_client(auth_version)
  File "/home/vcap/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/swiftclient/client.py", line 502, in _import_keystone_client
    variables to be set or overridden with -A, -U, or -K.''')
ClientException: 
Auth versions 2.0 and 3 require python-keystoneclient, install it or use Auth
version 1.0 which requires ST_AUTH, ST_USER, and ST_KEY environment
variables to be set or overridden with -A, -U, or -K.
```

Seems like the append wasn't causing an error, but exposing one. I'll update once this is sorted.

Comment: What is the actual error? Please edit your question to include the full traceback. If you're not sure where to find it, check your logs or enable debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated at the bottom of the traceback, I was missing the python-keystoneclient in both my application requirements and import statements.

I fixed this by adding

```
python-keystoneclient
```

to my requirements.txt (which is the requirements file for the python-heroku-buildpack), which then allowed me to add the import to my Flask app

```
import keystoneclient.v3 as keystoneclient
```